# Why when i move my first div to the top, the others does not move too?

Tags: html, css, animation

Imagine i have 3 div :

```
<div class="one animated">
    I'm the first div
</div>
<div class="two">
    second div
</div>
<div class="three">
    Last one
</div>
```

I have a code to move the first to the top :

```
.animated {
    animation: animation 2s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes animation {
    0%      { top: 0; opacity: 1 }
    100%    { top: -300px; opacity: 0 }
}
```

I don't understand why the first div move to top, but not the others.
The first one disappear so i want to replace the blank by my others div ...

Something like that :

```js
function test() {
   document.getElementById("sample").classList.add("animated");
}
```

```css
.one {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.animated {
    animation: animation 2s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes animation {
    0%      { top: 0; opacity: 1 }
    100%    { top: -300px; opacity: 0 }
}
```

```html
<div class="one" id="sample">
    I'm the first div
</div>
<div class="two">
    second div
</div>
<div class="three">
    Last one
</div>

<button onclick="test()">Test</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `absolute:position;` on `Keyframes`. This will make sure as soon as the `div` is hidden it automatically moves to the top.

> Also you can add additional `keyframes` attributes to make if smooth.

```js
function test() {
  document.getElementById("sample").classList.add("animated");
}
```

```css
.one {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.animated {
  animation: animation 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes animation {
  0% {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="one" id="sample">
  I'm the first div
</div>
<div class="two">
  second div
</div>
<div class="three">
  Last one
</div>

<button onclick="test()">Test</button>
```

Comment: Thanks @Manjuboyz  It needs to move to the top & 
Is it possible to make the result smooth?

Comment: yep, I changed the code now, it is smooth now, check the answer now.

Comment: Here is the another version: https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/v4j037d2/11/

Comment: I guess the other div can't move it will be suddenly ?

Comment: Yes, the div will be moved to the top as soon as the upper div disappeared, to handle the other divs I assume you have to use `js` for that too. not I am aware through keyframes.

Answer (score 0):

Add `position: absolute;` to `.animated` class in your `css`

```js
function test() {
   document.getElementById("sample").classList.add("animated");
}
```

```css
.one {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.animated {
    animation: animation 2s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    position: absolute; // Adding this will help
    transition: all 2s linear;
}

@keyframes animation {
    0%      { top: 0; opacity: 1; }
    50%     {top: -1; opacity: 0.5;}
    100%    { top: -300px; opacity: 0; }
}
```

```html
<div class="one" id="sample">
    I'm the first div
</div>
<div class="two">
    second div
</div>
<div class="three">
    Last one
</div>

<button onclick="test()">Test</button>
```

Comment: Thanks @Kirubel
Is it possible to make the result smooth?